# Lucene integration with SDG

Tags: spring, lucene, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are looking to use the newly added Lucene feature in Pivotal GemFire 9/Apache Geode.

For this, we would need to know if there are any examples for the Lucene integration with *Spring Data GemFire*?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. I have not had a whole lot of time to build more complete examples recently.

Although, I do have documentation on SDG's Pivotal GemFire / Lucene Integration support in the *Spring Data GemFire Reference Guide* [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#bootstrap:lucene).

Until more detailed examples are added, you can refer to the SDG test suite for the GemFire / Lucene Integration support, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/tree/2.0.0.RC2/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/search/lucene).

The [o.s.d.g.search.lucene.LuceneOperationsIntegrationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.RC2/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/search/lucene/LuceneOperationsIntegrationTests.java) class is perhaps the best place to start.

Pivotal GemFire's documentation on "*Apache Lucene Integration*" starts [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/tools_modules/lucene_integration.html).

There is information on the Apache Geode Wiki [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Lucene+Internals) (concerning architecture) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Lucene+Text+Search+on+Nested+Object) (new proposal for Lucene text searches on nested objects).

And finally, there was a recent blog post by Pivotal on "[*Using Pivotal GemFire/Apache Geode with Lucene Indexing for Application UI Typeahead*](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/using-pivotal-gemfire-apache-geode-with-lucene-indexing-for-application-ui-typeahead)", which uses *Spring*.

Hopefully this will get you started. Know that more is on its way and contributions are always appreciated.

Regards,
-John